# Pyplot imshow function displays only axis instead of image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I created a python function to convert every pixel of an image's colour to it's primary color. It gets the max value of the rgb values of each pixel and creates a new list with the only that color. For example if a pixel's rgb values are (250, 100, 23) it creates a new list with the value (256, 0, 0), as 250 is the max value, and appends it to a numpy array. Here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Tbc.png and here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage.data as data

def draw(list, img):
  #the problem is in this function
  arr = np.array(list)
  arr.reshape(np.shape(img))
  plt.imshow(arr)
  plt.show()
  
def convert(image):
  global x
  #I made x global because I wanted to see if the function worked and it worked
  x = []
  for i in image:
    for o in i:
      if(max(o) == o[0]):
        x.append([255, 0, 0])
      elif max(o) == o[1]:
        x.append([0, 255, 0])
      elif max(o) == o[2]:
        x.append([0, 0, 255])
  draw(x, image)

convert(data.rocket())
#data.rocket() is an image that is a numpy array of shape 427, 640, 3
#data.rocket() is a perfect array that works with the function
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the line:

```
arr.reshape(np.shape(img))
```

The method '.reshpe' does not work 'inplace' but it returns a new reorganized pointer to the array. The object arr, does not change its shape. if you don't want to change your code to much than, instead, do smth like:

```
arr = arr.reshape(np.shape(img))
```

But instead of making it a list and appending the pixels to it, I think it would be better to do smth like this:

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2, 2, 3))
maxs = np.argmax(image, axis = 2)
x = np.zeros_like(image)
indices = np.indices(image.shape[:-1])
x[indices[0].flatten(), indices[1].flatten(), maxs.flatten()] = 255
```

output:

```
image = 
[[[ 92  34 149]
  [110 171   0]]

 [[104  84 189]
  [121 211 177]]]
x = 
[[[  0   0 255]
  [  0 255   0]]
 [[  0   0 255]
  [  0 255   0]]]
```